# Adding text (Or getting CaretPosition) of RichTextBox in .Net Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a basic text editor app, and I aim to add a feature where the user can click a button and add premade text after where their cursor is.

I currently have this (using some code I found online)

`richTextBox1.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun(s);`

I intend for the string s to be the string to be added.

However, the RichTextBox in System.Windows.Forms does NOT contain a CaretPosition. I found one post from 2010 suggesting you use System.Windows.Control, however, that is no longer accessible in .Net Core, it depends on presentation framework.

So, is there any way I could get my goal (inserting a string after the mouse cursor, in a rich text box), in .net core?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getcharindexfromposition?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 the sample shows how to find the postion in the text when the user clicks on the control

Comment: The current position is returned by `SelectionStart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated2:

Use the following code to fully satisfy the richtextbox of the text text environment.:

```
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.SelectionStart, richTextBox1.TextLength);//Select everything after the cursor
string tmp = richTextBox1.SelectedText;//Copy them
richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";//Set to null
richTextBox1.AppendText("Hello world"+tmp);//Add the target string and add the original text
```

Updated1:

```
// Determine if there is any text in the Clipboard to paste into the text box.
if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) == true)
{
    IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    Clipboard.SetDataObject("Hello World");
    richTextBox1.Paste();
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
}
else
{
    Clipboard.SetDataObject("Hello World");
    richTextBox1.Paste();
}
```

This action preserves the contents of the original pasteboard.

Only works if the clipboard is data. I will continue to update after I think about it.

Original:
You only need to use the clipboard and [paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.paste?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#definition) method to insert the specified string after the specified cursor.

```
 Clipboard.SetDataObject("Hello World");
 richTextBox1.Paste();
 Clipboard.Clear();
```

[image]

Change it yourself according to your needs.

Comment: But then surely you have to wipe out whatever is on the user's clipboard which is incredibly rude

Comment: I didn't really understand it. My point is, I have some useful thing on my clipboard that I need, I click a button in your program and my useful thing is gone, replaced by your Hello World.. no?

Comment: Is there any way to get the current clip board text before copying to copy it back after the operation?

Comment: @CaiusJard After reading the material carefully and thinking it over and over again, it is really bad practice to use the customer's pasteboard without permission. Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: @bruh it's a bit of what we call an XY problem. There is some problem X ("insert text at cursor pos") and some suggestion of a solution ("set the clipboard and do a paste") but that then leads to another problem ("users clipboard is wiped") Y. It doesn't then mean you must try and solve the Y problem caused by the first solution; it would be preferable to find a different solution to the X problem rather than keep piling workaround on top of workaround on top of workaround to resolve the "every solution causes another problem".Look at SelectionStart like Jimi suggested and Jiale guided